# How do I configure Google Chrome to open zip files in file-roller instead of Nautilus?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, zip, archiving, nautilus

When I download a .zip file using Google Chrome on Linux, upon clicking it the .zip file opens my Downloads folder in Nautilus, *not* the .zip file in file-roller. Ironically, Google is mum on the subject, with most results pointing to Windows 7's Default Programs dialog.

Has a way to fix this arisen since the last Google Chrome update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the application that opens .zip filetype archives with the command xdg-open, which is the way used by Chrome/Chromium to open files.

To do that, follow these steps:

1. Find the name of the program that you want to use. In your case is file-roller, and in my case was engrampa, because I'm using Linux Mint with MATE.
2. Open a terminal and write:

   xdg-mime default programname.desktop application/zip

   Change "programname" with file-roller, engrampa or any other program you want to use.
3. If you want, test it by writing:

   xdg-mime query default application/zip

   And it should say file-roller.desktop, and now write:

   xdg-open /path/to/a/zip/file.zip

   And it should open on your program.

Now Chrome/Chromium should open them right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Google Chrome ver. 21.0.1180.75 on Ubuntu 12.04. When I download a .zip file from my e-mail account, I click on the little blue dropdown arrow to the right of the filename in the download bar and then on **always open files of this type**.
Also, check the Downloads section in Chrome's advanced settings and you should see what is shown in the lower part of the picture.
Subsequently, downloading a .zip file automatically displays the .zip file in File Roller and not in Nautilus.

[image: auto-open zip files]

Comment: That made no difference. It still opens in Nautilus instead of file-roller.